# Getting notified by Angular when download ends

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the following code to trigger a file download:

```
$scope.download = function(contract) {
var downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');
            downloadLink.attr('href', "application/octet-stream," + url);
            downloadLink.attr('download', contract.id + '.pdf');
            downloadLink[0].click();
 }
```

This code is executed on a click event associated to a button like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="download(contract)" 
id="{{contract.id}}_download_button" target="_parent">PDF</button>
```

I have many buttons: one per contract shown.

Before download starts, however, there could be a delay of a few seconds. I would like to inform the user that a click has been received, e.g. by disabling the button until download starts.
If this is not possible, what's the best way to manage this situation?
Thanks.

Comment: When the click is called do you know when the download starts, so you get a callback or any kind of event?

Comment: That's actually my question: do I know that, given that I just click on the  element I created to start the download?

Comment: You could just use ng-disabled based on a boolean that you set. So set to true on first line of download function and then false after the click() is called

Comment: OK, but I am not enabling it after the download has started, but just when the download request is sent.

Comment: So are you saying there is a delay between the actual click and the first line of the download function gets hit?

Comment: I am saying that the PDF I am downloading is generated on the fly, so there is a delay between the click (request to generate and download the pdf) and the download start.